# Popping back to subview speeds up video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have a `UIView` with a video as its background. When I present another subview, and then pop back to the one with the video, this happens:

[Video [11 seconds]](http://wesleypeeters.com/speedup.mov) (kept it a video since a GIF wouldn't have the same framerate, and the problem would be less clear.)

As you can see, the video speeds up, and then slows down when it reaches a certain point. What I'd like to accomplish is for the video to always keep playing at it's normal speed, and thus eliminate the speedup happening.

This is the code used for the showing of the video:

```
self.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

Does AVPlayer perhaps have an option to disable this, or is there a way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: stop video in "viewWillDisappear" and after popback start video in "viewWillAppear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume this is happening because the video keeps playing while the other view controller is presented on the screen.
What I would try to solve this is to pause the video in `viewWillDisappear` and then play it again in `viewWillAppear`.